# Passing callback to Invoke

Tags: c#

I am having trouble figuring out how to use Invoke with a callback as a parameter. CallbackMethod is the callback in this example and I'm trying to invoke MyFunc (of any given type) and pass it CallbackMethod as the callback.

MyFunc is the template function I am trying to invoke.

The problem is that CallbackMethod is a method and does not like to be converted to an object. It works just fine if I do not use invoke, but since Invoke requires an object array I am not sure what to do. I've tried maaany different ways around it but I can't seem to find one that works.

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(MyType).GetMethod("MyFunc");
mi.MakeGenericMethod(mType).Invoke(this.MyTypeInstance, new object[] { CallbackMethod });

int MyFunc<T>(Action<T> callback) where T : class, new();

public void CallbackMethod<T>(T msg)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Can you just cast it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the method to a delegate.

```
mi.MakeGenericMethod(mType).Invoke(this.MyTypeInstance, 
     new object[] { (Action<object>)CallbackMethod });
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks alexw, apparently I was overthinking this problem. For some reason I never tried casting it as an Action<object>, which seems to be the magic solution.

Comment: Follow up: What if you had to do this in 3.5? For windows xp compatibility reasons I'm finding that I am stuck using 3.5, which doesn't seem to support this syntax :/

Comment: Which method isn't working? Is it a compile time or runtime error?

Comment: It is a runtime error. "Object of type 'System.Action[object] cannot be converted to type 'system.action[remote_delegate_type]'.


I tried boxing the callbackmethod into a delegate object earlier (Action<base_object>) but it still ends up with a runtime error.
 
The delegate that I'm passing in only needs the base class which all the other classes inherit so it should work. Hopefully it is still possible to do on 3.5.

Comment: Can you cast to `object` first? `(Action<object>)(object)CallbackMethod `

Comment: Tried that too. I tried putting it into object, Action<object>, delegate, and Action<base_object>. I am trying right now a compromise of using .net 4.0 rather than 3.5, since it is supported by xp, even though it is not the ideal version. It seems like it will work so far.